# Getting different times from ngx bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx bootstrap datepicker. On selecting the date the time value is either midnight or hours subtracted from midnight from the next day.

For eg if today is 2nd of April it will either be 2nd of April 00:00 or 2ng of April (24:00 - x) where GMT + x is the current timezone. I actually only need the date part and the time part is irrelevant but in the first scenario when the API adjusts it for UTC the date one day behind.

```
<input type="text" bsDatepicker class="form-control" formControlName="date" placeholder="Date" />
```

The documentation of ngx bootstrap has mentioned a "useUtc" property but whether I use it as

`[useUtc] = "true"` or `[bsConfig]="{useUtc = 'true'}"`
the timezone in the date object is still the local one.

Comment: Which server do you use? You need to return date in UTC format from server.

Comment: But why are random time values being alloted?

Comment: DateTime auto convert to local UTC when you return from server non-utc datetime. Check please what came from server. Convert to local if you use .net based server.

Comment: I am using .NET core. But this is an input, so from angular I am getting different time values on selecting different dates.